# .NET tooltip control which can be shown anywhere on a screen

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Can someone recommend me a free .NET Windows Forms tooltip control which can be displayed anywhere on the screen (not tied to a particular control).

Comment: Can you describe the intended use a bit more in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the standard ToolTip control in the Windows.Forms namespace. ToolTip has a Show method which takes a Point parameter that you can use to display the tip when and where you want it. The ToolTip does **not** have to be associated with a control.

Answer (score 0):

Add a standard Tooltip control to a form? It has to be hosted somewhere. Your application does not 'own' the desktop so it is only applicable when your applications has the focus. Otherwise, investigate the System Tray.